# Type class polymorphism with overloaded numeric and string literals

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, overloading, typeclass

I'm trying to write some EDSL for assigning values to keys. So I have the following data type for value:

```
data Value = B Bool | I Int
```

I want to have unified way to convert different values to objects of type `Value`. So I've created the following type class:

```
class    ToValue a    where toValue :: a -> Value
instance ToValue Bool where toValue = B
instance ToValue Int  where toValue = I
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile:

```
foo :: [Value]
foo = [toValue True, toValue 3]
```

I understand the reason why. But this makes me sad. I don't really understand how to solve this problem... And things become more difficult if I have `-XOverloadedStrings` enabled and I want to add `T Text` constructor to my `Value` type.

My final goal is to have ability to write something like this:

```
foo :: [(Text, Value)]
foo = [ "key1" !!! True
      , "key2" !!! 42
      , "key3" !!! "foo"
      , "key4" !!! [5, 7, 10]
      ]
```

I understand that I can always wrap manually every value into corresponding constuctor but I'd prefer to avoid that (since in my real life constructors are longer than one letter and code doesn't really decrease in noise with constructors).

What can I do to achieve the closest possible implementation? I would like to avoid unsafe `Num` instance for `Value` if possible...

Comment: It turns out `ExtendedDefaultRules` work. I thought it was a GHCi-only thing for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#extension-ExtendedDefaultRules). (It is enabled by default in GHCi, and the pragma enables it in GHC.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

default (Int, String)

class Value a where
  toValue :: a -> String

instance Value Int where
  toValue = show

instance Value String where
  toValue = id

main = do
  print (toValue 3)    -- would otherwise be ambiguous
  print (toValue "x")
```

---

#### Old answer

If I understand correctly, the goal here is to keep the syntax uniform while properly specializing literals. One way is to use Template Haskell, so `foo` might look like

```
foo = [$(toValue [|True|]), $(toValue [|3|])]
```

or

```
foo = [ [toValue| True |], [toValue| 3 |] ]
```

The latter is less dollar-noisy, but implementing a custom quote requires an expression parser and *template-haskell* doesn't provide one.

Comment: Compiler plugins would be another way of solving this, but I don't know anything about writing one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Great suggestions :+1: I have experience with writing ghc plugins. And this is not really a thing a person want to do... Solution with `-XExtendedDefaultRules` looks already quite good to me!